# Comparing LED light with fluorescence light, which one is better in terms of energy conservation?

Tags: everyday-life, semiconductor-physics

Comparing LED light with fluorescence light, which one is better in terms of energy conservation and why? I want to switch to one of the choice for above for home lighting, so any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They are different but which is better?  Your question is too vague to answer.  What is your criteria for "better"?

Comment: @ user6972: In terms of energy conservation.

Comment: In general LED's GIYF: http://eartheasy.com/live_led_bulbs_comparison.html

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: Do you mean energy conservation or energy efficiency?

Comment: I think there *is* fundamental physics to be had here (as George E. Smith's answer shows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern white LEDs are more efficient (lumens per Watt) than any sort of fluorescent tube, or compact fluorescent.   The advantage is fundamental.

Fluorescent tubes or compact fluorescent lamps, have a low pressure plasma discharge that emits Ultra-Violet radiation.  It emits essentially NO visible light.

So 100% of the light output is emitted by the phosphor coating on the inside walls of the fluorescent tube.   The phosphor absorbs some or all of the UV radiation, which then stimulates the fluorescence of the phosphor, so it glows in some visible wavelength.  In practice, the phosphor is a mix of materials that fluoresce at different wavelengths, usually a green or yellow, or blue green and usually some red phosphor.

A red photon at around 650 nm wavelength has about 2 electron Volts of energy.   A UV photon at half that wavelength, 325 nm, has 4 electron Volts of energy.

When the phosphor absorbs a 4 eV photon, and emits a 2 eV photon (red) , there is an energy loss of 2 eV which is converted to waste heat.   This is known as the "Stokes Shift" loss, and occurs, whenever high energy photons excite lower energy fluorescence.

So in a fluorescent tube, 100% of the light is generated by fluorescence involving Stokes Shift losses.

White LEDs are somewhat different.  By far the most common are known as "Blue pumped" white LEDs.    Instead of generating high eV UV photons, the basic LED chip emits a narrow blue emission, at about 460 nm wavelength, generally in the 450-470 range.

A portion of this blue light get absorbed in a yellow emitting phosphor which combined with the remaining blue photons, creates the white light.   The Blue residual photons involve NO Stokes shift loss, and only the broad yellow phosphor emission involves a Stokes shift loss.   Usually some form of red phosphor is also needed to give a better white illumination with good color rendition.

So Blue pumped white LEDs can always be more efficient than any fluorescent, since the blue part of the spectrum is generated without the Stokes loss.

Even higher efficiency can be obtained by using either three or four color LEDs, Blue, (Green), Yellow, and Red, so there is NO Stokes shift loss at all.  This is quite difficult to keep constant color over Temperature and drive current, so it is expensive.

Warm white LEDs (or fluorescents) are inherently less efficient, that daylight white ones, because a red phosphor must be added, and all conventional red phosphors emit a very broad red spectrum.  The long wave end of the red spectrum contributes very little visible light, so it wastes a lot of extra energy.

My house is entirely illuminated with readily available off the shelf blue pumped white LEDs.  NO incandescents, and NO fluorescents, so NO mercury.